# Display data in a 2 column Table

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

i'm new to asp.net mvc. I'm displaying data from a linq to sql query but unsure how to render a a list of data in a 2 column table.

eg. A list of products. I've seen this example, but wondering if there are any other suggestions - http://haacked.com/archive/2010/05/05/asp-net-mvc-tabular-display-template.aspx.

Hence if i have 6 products returned, i want them displayed in a table in this format, see below.

[image]
regards

Comment: I'm not too sure what you are asking here? All Phil is doing is writing his own template - looping over the data and creating a table. Exactly what you want no? You can alter his template however you want to fit your needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is what i came up with, it's not the cleanest code, but there doesn't seem to be a clear cut way of doing this.

```
<table>
<%
        int productCount = 0;

        foreach (var x in Model)
        {
            productCount++;

            if (productCount % 2 == 1)
            {
            %>
               <tr>
                    <td>                          
                        <%=Html.Encode(x.ProductId)%>              
                    </td>
            <%
            }
            else
            {
             %>
               <td>
                     <%=Html.Encode(x.ProductId)%>  
                </td>
              </tr>
           <% }
        }

        if (productCount % 2 == 1)
        {%>
            <td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
        <%}%>

</table>
```

Answer (score 4):

You could also use div's instead of a table (this is what I would do to be honest), which would make it a LOT cleaner:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .products { width:600px; }
    .product { width:280px; margin-right:20px; float:left; height:150px; }
</style>

<div class="products">
    <% foreach (var item in Model) { %>    
    <div class="product">
        <%: item.SomeProperty %>
        <%: item.AnotherProperty %>
    </div>
    <% } %>
    <div style="clear:left;"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't the cleanest (definitely ugly to look at)... but you could add a boolean that you toggle so you can alternate between rendering the left and right column when rendering each product. IE:

```
<table>
<% bool left = true;
foreach (var item in Model) { %>
  <%: left ? "<tr>" : "" %>
  <td>
    <%: item.SomeProperty %>
  </td>
  <%: !left ? "</tr>" : "" %>
<% left = !left; } %>
<% if (!left) { //need to end the lastrow if we had an odd number of items %>
  <td></td>
</tr>
<% } %>
</table>
```

There is probably a better way to do this, but this is what first comes to mind.

Comment: thanks for this, i'm evaluating this before i vote for it. i'm surprised this in't easier.

Answer (score -1):

I presume what you are asking is how to write a table without having to write/use a template as in the haacked.com blog post.  Its simple.  Just type the definition into the view itself.  Remember that, in a sense, a view is just a template, that takes your model and spits out html.

Using the haacked.com article, and assuming you have a strongly typed view using a Model that holds the results of your query, lets say, an IEnumerable MyData, just type into your view:

```
<table>
  <tr>       
    <th>
      Column Name 1
    </th>
    <th>
      Column Name 2
    </th>
  </tr>
    <% foreach (var x in Model.MyData) { %>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <%: x.Column1 %>
      </td>
      <td>
        <%: x.Column2 %>
      </td>
      <% } %>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The above assumes that each object in MyData has two properties, Column1 and Column2.  Adapt, style to taste and enjoy.

Comment: The above also assumes mvc 2.  Otherwise, you need to replace <%: with <%=.  If the data comes from user input, in mvc 1 you have to html encode the data to avoid xss.  The mvc 2 syntax (<%: %>) html encodes for you, so not necessary in that case.

Comment: hi, when i meant 2 columns , i mean 2 products per table row, as per my now amended example. does that make sense?

Comment: Next time, could you put some more effort into writing a clear question? I'm outta here.